# Uninitialized variable

Tags: c, initialization, gtk

I am having a problem. I don't know why but compiler throws out error:

> error: 'tmp' is used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]|

In that code where on line where *sprintf()* is:

```
void OknoMin(){

char *tmp;
window_miny = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window_miny), "LICZBA MIN");
gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window_miny), GTK_WIN_POS_NONE);
gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window_odkryte), 150,30);

miny=gtk_entry_new();
sprintf(tmp,"%d",k);
gtk_entry_set_text((GtkEntry*)miny,tmp);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window_miny), miny);

g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window_miny), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
g_signal_connect_after( miny, "insert-text", G_CALLBACK(check_after), NULL );
gtk_widget_show_all(window_miny);}
```

I tried to clean whole project but I still get that error. I think I missed some basics here but I don't really know where I made a mistake. It is worth to mention that I use similar code in other function and it works. Any ideas?

Comment: allocate space for `tmp`. `malloc()` or use an array `char tmp[100];`

Comment: Another way (not so good): `char buffer[100]; char *tmp = buffer;`

Comment: @MikeCAT, why can't he use `buffer` in place of `tmp`, why is another variable needed.

Comment: Wow, it works. Never had to use malloc before but i guess now i will :)

Comment: As a side note, you could also replace `sprintf` with a safer version, e.g. `snprintf` or make sure that you allocate enough memory to store all the digits of an integer on your platform.

Comment: @Haris That is the reason why I marked this code as not so good. It may be useful if you need to switch buffer to use.

Comment: @Darknez: If using `malloc()` to allocate memory on the heap instead of using an array on the stack, do not forget to `free()` the memory, when not needed an ymore, to not eat away the process's memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tmp` is definitely uninitialized, so the compiler told so. Initialize the variable.

Instead of that, I think using an array is better for this case (only string converted from one integer will be stored in the buffer).

```
void OknoMin(){

    char tmp[64]; /* *tmp -> tmp[64] */
    window_miny = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window_miny), "LICZBA MIN");
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window_miny), GTK_WIN_POS_NONE);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window_odkryte), 150,30);

    miny=gtk_entry_new();
    sprintf(tmp,"%d",k);
    gtk_entry_set_text((GtkEntry*)miny,tmp);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window_miny), miny);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window_miny), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    g_signal_connect_after( miny, "insert-text", G_CALLBACK(check_after), NULL );
    gtk_widget_show_all(window_miny);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but Harris told me to use malloc() which i find faster method. Also now i see why it was not initialized, thanks for help :)

Comment: @Darknez: Allocating memory on the stack (as per this answer) probably is faster than doing it via the heap. Also please see my comment to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using GTK+ you're also using GLib, which gives you a much better method: [`g_strdup_printf()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strdup-printf). This allocates the right amount of memory for you. Free with [`g_free()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Memory-Allocation.html#g-free). (You can free immediately after calling one of the `gtk_xxx_set_yyy()` methods; GTK+ copies all its strings.)